# PICkit 2: find out why my processor is crashing

Tags: microcontroller, pic, pickit

I have some buggy code, which is causing my processor to crash. I'm almost certain in what function it's in, but I don't know how to narrow down what the crash is, or where it is, for that matter. I know this isn't a Microchip support forum but I suspect someone there knows how to find out what the problem is. I am **not asking for the solution** but instead how to find the solution. I have a PICkit 2 with software v2.32.0, and I'm debugging a dsPIC33FJ128GP802.

Comment: @ThomasO, This is not nearly enough information. If you post some code we could review the function, you could explain more about the situation, or you could expand on what your issue is with the PICkit 2.

Comment: @Kortuk, I'm asking how to trace the problem, not what the problem is. Once I find the line of code or even the type of crash (division by zero, memory access violation, etc.) I can begin fixing it myself.

Comment: Yes, but there is such an expansive set of options available with your description I doubt you can get a concise path. Currently you are telling us your debugger and asking us to tell you every possibility that causes an embedded system to crash, we do not even know your compiler.

Comment: @Kortuk, you misunderstand my question. I am asking how to find out what the problem  is, not what the problem actually is.

Comment: @Thomas O Are you asking how to use a debugger?

Comment: @kellenjb, I suppose, specifically the PICkit 2. I've used it for basic debugging but the problem is, it never tells you why the chip crashed - only "Target Halted" when it does.

Comment: @Thomas O This is one of the main things that makes embedding programming difficult. It is a lot to expect a microcontroller to know why it crashed. There really isn't any better advice then what @kortuk has already answered.

Comment: @ThomasO, Asking how to find the solution is the same as asking for it. We will have to list every possible problem that you could have, you are not giving enough detail for this to be answered. I understand that you want to learn how to debug these issues, but there is no way we can tell you to just "Do A, then B, and if nothing else, Do C". This does not exist in the embedded world. It is a bit easier to do on computer programming but you have never lived until you have a resource lock between threads.

Comment: @Kellenjb, so it would seem a limitation of the debug hardware? The processor has interrupts/traps for things like divide by zero, so I was thinking of setting up an ISR... maybe get it to pulse an IO indicating the type of crash.

Comment: @Thomas O side note, dividing on a microcontroller is very poor practice unless you absolutely have to. It is much better to do bit shifting.

Comment: @kellenjb, the dsPIC33F has a 19-cycle hardware divider, I don't use it often, but never... that would be wrong.

Comment: @ThomasO, I use MSP430s without multiply hardware. I found a way to remove all divides, excluding binary ones.

Comment: What is a "crash" on a microcontroller anyway?

Comment: @AndreKR, on most microcontrollers a "crash" is defined as an unexpected reset. MCUs rarely freeze, they just go into a reset or shutdown mode in case of a disallowed condition. In my case, it was resetting every so often, seemingly randomly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try a breakpoint. Place a breakpoint in the function where you think it is crashing. I am not sure if the PICkit 2 supports this.

#### Why Firmware Guys/Gals Love Extra Digital I/O

Even easier, use a couple of those debug lines. You may know them as unused digital I/O, but they are debug lines as far as I am concerned. At key points bring the line high and after that key point is done bring it low. Move these about and find which one does not go low again. The clock cycle required to bring the line high or low will only mildly affect code but allow your oscope to tell you an important story!

#### More about breakpoints.

Place your break-point in your possibly faulty function and single step it. If you have too many interrupts for this to work, try placing the break point at intervals, removing the last one if you hit your maximum number of breakpoints. when you do not hit one you have found your bug. if you think there is a specific case where it crashes, put an if statement that will be true in that case and place a _nop() that you can breakpoint on.

#### Interrupt service Routines

Place all unused ISRs to go to a special function that will set pins to an error state and lock in place so that you can see an ISR that should not be enabled is.

Answer (score 5):

You say that you don't know how to narrow it down:

Divide and conquer - remove as much code as you can until the fault goes away. With some experimentation you'll likely cut your search down hugely.

As suggested, use spare I/O lines to signal points in your code. Ideally, you might be able to have a line showing entry and exit from a subroutine and correlate this on a scope with the fault occurring.

Some general tips:

- Build a good test case so you can reproduce the fault on demand
- Remove *everything* non-essential to reproducing the fault
- Keep your ISRs as short as possible - do what you have to then return
- Understand and use the volatile keyword in C
- Don't rely on debuggers, know your code and rely on a debug LED. Generally debuggers just don't work well for realtime systems

Comment: Agreed, There is no magic way to have the debugger halt on crash, you can only get it to halt on reset. Cut the code, although most of the bugs I wish I could find have been due to the large amount of things running.

Comment: When I first started in embedded I did not know the volatile keyword in C. May did I hate having to turn on the optimizer, nothing ever worked.

Comment: The quickest way to divide and conquer is to get the diff between the working and nonworking code from version control. Some guys like to write the entire program in one step and then debug it in a marathon debugging session. That doesn't work in embedded programming. Make small changes and tst thoroughly before moving on.

Comment: I love version control. There is no single thing that increases productivity more than version control for myself.

Answer (score 4):

The Freescale HCS08 family has a "System Reset Status" register which is set based on the source for the last reset, identifying things like LVD, POR, debugger reset, illegal op-code, illegal address access, watchdog timeout, loss of clock, and hardware (external reset).   Might there be an equivalent on PICs?

It has saved me maybe 50% pain after learning to use it as it clues you into the possible source of the error.  A breakpoint only works if you know roughly where *and when* the code will cause a fatal error, otherwise you may have to step thousands of times, likely through the same code, until you hit the snafu.

**Edit:** Here's the stupid code I wrote for it (HCS08-only obviously).  Not that pretty, but hey, I'm a hardware developer, not software.

```
#ifdef Debug_MP16VLF
    const char rstsrc[] = "Source  :";
    const char clrColors[] = "\x1B[0m";

    const char * const rst_srcs[] = {
        " \x1B[32mPower On Reset",      " \x1B[32mReset Pin", 
        " \x1B[31mWatchdog",            " \x1B[35mIllegal Opcode",
        " \x1B[36mIllegal Address",     " \x1B[33mLow Voltage Detect",
        " \x1B[33mDebugger Reset"
    };
    enum rst_srcs_idxs{
        RST_POR,                        RST_PIN,
        RST_COP,                        RST_ILOP,
        RST_ILAD,                       RST_LVD, 
        RST_DBG
    };
#endif
```

...

```
#   ifdef Debug_MP16VLF
        // Find reason(s) for reset and display
        print_str(rstsrc, 0, 1);
        if (SRS_LVD) {
            if (SRS_POR) print_str(rst_srcs[RST_POR], 0, 1);
            print_str(rst_srcs[RST_LVD], 0, 1);
        } else if (SRS) {
            // possible multiple reset sources
            uint8_t i, j;
            for (i = SRS_ILAD_MASK, j = RST_ILAD;
                 i <= SRS_PIN_MASK;
                 i <<= 1, j--) {
                if (i & SRS) print_str(rst_srcs[j], 0, 1);
            }
        } else {
            print_str(rst_srcs[RST_DBG], 0, 1);
        }
        print_str(clrColors, 1, 1);
#   endif
```

Comment: He said he was already pretty sure what function it was in. Hopefully his functions aren't very long.

Comment: Regardless, I forget to mention this, in a nicer code I have written before when it powers up it records what interrupted the device on last run and logs or TX's it so that debugging is easier.

Comment: @kellenjb, Unfortunately my functions are very long - one is 500 instructions!

Comment: @Thomas: Divide and conquer.  Are you writing in assembly?  By "instruction" do you actually mean assembly instruction or line of C?

Comment: @Nick T, they are mostly C.

Comment: @ThomasO, The solution to long functions is more short ones.

Comment: @kortuk, and making it slower... the code is about 40-50 lines, it's just it uses complicated instructions and bit math.

Comment: @thomasO, Are you not using an optimizer? even if you are not you should be able to inline functions. More functions can actually speed up code. A good optimizer can take advantage of the new space to make your system more optimized. for example, if most of your math is on one variable in a subsection they can smack it in a register and take care of it.

Comment: The PIC equivalent is the RCON register.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of narrowing a crash down, use a **binary search** technique.  Using one of the methods described in the other answers (breakpoints or I/O lines going to a scope or LED), pick a point halfway through the function you suspect the problem is in, and set the BP there.  If the BP is hit (or the LED lights), the problem is in the second half of the code (since the program didn't crash).  If it isn't, it is in the first half.

Whichever half is suspect, divide that section in half and set a new BP at the midpoint.  If the BP is hit, the problem is in the other part of the code (now narrowed down to a quarter if the function).  Keep repeating this process if necessary and it will isolate the problem down to a single line of code.

Because it is using a binary search, this is the fastest method to narrow down where a crash is occurring.

Comment: Nice, I like it. I still thinking using shorter functions is a better method, but this method works.

Comment: This doesn't cover for the very real possibility of a pointer being corrupted in one part of memory affecting another entirely unrelated function.

Comment: @Thomas, if that is the problem, this technique should still narrow down where the pointer is affecting the code.  You may have to extend the scope beyond your suspected function.  Because of the log base 2 nature of the search, you can even use this to track down errors in a several thousand line program fairly efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Watch for stack overflows.  Maybe you have too many nested calls to functions.  Try to iron it out by calling them one after another where possible.
Some functions might as well be replaced by macros.  That might add a bit more weight to your code, but will keep your stack low.